# "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" error while trying to get AppDelegate

Tags: ios, facebook, appdelegate

I follow Facebook's instruction (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/) and try to implement a facebook login button.  However, I get the "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" error while trying to call the application delegate method.

The method:

```
- (IBAction)pressFBLogin:(id)sender {
    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}
```

From the error, I think it is memory pointer error pointing to a wrong instance.  I set the break point at:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

It did reach this statement, so nothing wrong with action bound.  The error shows up when it tries to run the next statement:

```
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
```

There is one thing I found from the watch window that seems strange when I do the debug is the appDelegate variable.  When break point is at

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Variable is shown as:

```
appDelegate = (MyViewController *)0x003b9a10
> UIViewController(UIViewController)
> delegate = (objc_object *) 0x0033edb0
```

After the variable assignment, and break point is at

```
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
```

Variable is shown as:

```
appDelegate = (MyViewController *)0x00316480
> UIViewController(UIViewController)
> delegate = (objc_object *) 0x00000000
```

In neither stage, the appDelegate seems to be an object of MyAppDelegate.

Comment: Sounds as if you mistakenly assigned some viewController's delegate towards your app delegate.

Comment: Yes, it seems like that but I cannot locate the source that cause this.  I do have an "delegate" property in MyViewController, I try rename that property to "mydelegate", but the same error still shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue.  It ends up to be nothing wrong with appDelegate variable. The problem is very simple: a little typo between my header and my implementation file of the openSessionWithAllowLoginUI function.  Such an issue usually will be detected at compile time as error, I am surprise there is no build error on such a issue, instead just a warning of incomplete implementation...

Answer (score 0):

I m facing this same crash, I have solved this by adding

> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

> var window: UIWindow?

In my APP Delegate, this solved my issue. I m using Xcode 12.3, This crash happens when I m trying to signup by using firebase auth